# Pass variable with Link React Router Dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-props

i have some problem with passing a variable with Link
please I need your help.
I need to click de SELECT Link and redirect to contact, and automatically select de Package in the input below

I'm trying to do like that, and give an error: props is undefined

here is the packages file when there is the Link

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "./Packages.css"

const Package = () => {

    return (
        <div className="packages-container">
        
            <div className="packages">

                <div className="package one">
                    <img
                        className="silver"
                        src="photos/silver.png"
                        alt="silver package"
                    />
                    <Link
                        className="package-btn"

                        to={'/contact/' + 1}>
                        SELECT
                            </Link>
                </div>

                <div className="package two">
                    <img
                        className="gold"
                        src="photos/gold.png"
                        alt="silver package"
                    />
                    <Link
                        className="package-btn"
                        packageId="2"
                        to={'/contact/' + 2}>
                        SELECT
                            </Link>
                </div>

            </div>
    )
}
export default Package
```

And here is the page contact, where i need to automatically select the input with the correct package

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, Fragment } from 'react';
import "./Contact.css"
import Layout from "../Layout/Layout"
import FadeIn from 'react-fade-in';
import emailjs from 'emailjs-com';


const Contacts = () => {

    console.log(this.props.match.params.id);

    const Contact = () => {
        useEffect(() => {
            window.scrollTo(0, 0)
        }, [])

        
        const form = showForm => (
            showForm && <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <label htmlFor="how">Which Package?<span className="optional">*</span></label>
                <select
                    name="pack"
                    className="contact-input package"
                    onChange={handleChange("pack")}
                    value={pack}
                    required>
                    <option value="" style={{ display: "none" }}> -- Select an option -- </option>
                    <option value="Gold Package">Gold Package</option>
                    <option value="Platinum Package">Platinum Package</option>
                    <option value="Silver Package">Silver Package</option>
                </select>

                

                <button type="submit">Send</button>
            </form>
        );
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <h3 className="contact-header">
                    Questions? <br />
            Want to reserve a date? <br />
            Contact Us! <br />
                </h3>
                {form(data.showForm)}
                {showLoading(data.loading)}
                {showSuccess(data.success)}
            </Fragment>
        );
    }

    

    return {
        Contact,
        ContactPage
    }
}
export default Contacts;
```

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

Functional components are "instanceless" and don't have a defined `this` to have `props` bounded to.

## Solution

Access the props object that is likely passed to the rendered component.

```
const Contacts = (props) => { // <-- props
  console.log(props.match.params.id);
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I am new to reactjs but I am unable to figure out where are you passing the props. Maybe that's the reason that the props are undefined.